# Software for maximum spacing estimation for 3-parameter extreme value distribution

Tags: statistics

- Non-proprietary
- Preferably expressed in Python
- 'Nice' credentials, if possible
- Also would be nice if it were in a form suitable for inclusion as one of the alternatives for fitting parameters in scipy.stats

Thanks!

Comment: OK. I still have no idea what you're looking for, but that might be just me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time I hear "statistics and free" or "statistics and $language" (python in your case) I immediately think of R and the bindings available for it.

Comment: You're right. There's a product described at https://rdrr.io/cran/lmomco/man/mps2par.html. I will look for the source code. Thank you.